# ColdFusion 10: Handling and Logging Errors With New REST API

Tags: rest, coldfusion, error-handling, coldfusion-10

I'm using ColdFusion 10's new REST API: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/restful-web-services.html

Whenever there's an exception, the API handles it nicely and automatically returns something like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Length: 52
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Fri, 22 Feb 2013 01:07:49 GMT

{"Message":"Element FOO is undefined in ARGUMENTS."}
```

The problem is that neither of the following gets called:

- Site-wide Error Handler
- Application.cfc's onError

It seems like the REST API handles the error and the exception doesn't bubble up.  I like to send myself an email (with error details) whenever server-side errors occur.  Any thoughts on how I can do with the new REST API?

Comment: file a bug report?  https://bugbase.adobe.com/

Comment: Thanks. Filed a bug here: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3506757

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not ideal, but you could add a try / catch in each method that sends you an email on error then rethrows.

Comment: Yes, that would work, but it would be crazy.  The reason why we use frameworks is so that we don't have to do such things.

Comment: Much as it pains me to say it, this is about the best one can do. I tried to find a better way: http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/07/rest-requests-dont-seem-to-correctly.html, but drew a blank. ColdFusion is workin against its own developers again.

Comment: Yes, this and other similar problems with CF 10's REST led me straight to a different framework, namely Relaxation.

Answer (score 1):

Site wide error handler works with REST services. Whiles invoking a REST service, user can specify the "Accept" Header. If the user specifies the accept header as xml or json, the error is caught and a struct with error code and message is serialized to appropriate format. In this case the site wide error handler is not invoked. It is not good to send the whole HTML content in JSON or XML. But if the requested Content-Type is text/html, then the Site wide handler is invoked and the HTML is returned as the response.

Comment: So in other words, the site-wide error handler only works if the API returns HTML?  I don't know of any properly designed REST API that returns HTML, so I don't see this as being very useful.  I think Adobe needs to fix this as soon as possible.

Comment: What @paul-nibin says here is not borne out by my own research. See http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/07/rest-requests-dont-seem-to-correctly.html. I acknolwedge that Paul is the Adobe ColdFusion Team developer who did this work, but code trumps job title.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are using to consume the web service, but assuming it's ColdFusion, you can use cfhttp and its throwonerror attribute:

```
<cftry>
    <cfhttp
        url="http://localhost:8500/rest/restapp/crudService/1"
        method="get"
        timeout="5"
        throwonerror="yes" />

    <cfcatch type="Any">
        <!--- email yourself the error details --->
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

That way you can use cfcatch to trap the 500 error that was returned and then email your self the cfcatch dump (or however you like to email error details).

Comment: What consumes the web service is irrelevant to the question - this is trapping errors client-side, and the question is asking how to do it server-side.

Comment: This is a public API, so many different sources will consume it (e.g. browser via JavaScript, 3rd parties, etc.).  @PeterBoughton is correct that this I need a solution which is independent of the consumer.  Everything needs be handled on the server.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed, but **only available in CF11**.

Quote:

> This is fixed in the latest ColdFusion11 release.

-- Hari Krishna Kallae

https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3506757

**UPDATE**

Hotfix for CF10 will be available on the next update (targeted for mid-Aug, 2014)